# Need some suggestion while updating data in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, sql-update

I have a scenario where I have around 10 forms in the same page, each carries same number of fields i.e. each form has 2 textboxes and 2 dropdowns.

Now, a user can update any field of any form and press update button. This would update data of all forms in the database.

Now I have 2 options. Either to update data of every form irrespective the data is changed or not OR check the data of every form (using Java comparable interface maybe) and update only altered data (or update altered form at most).

Which do you think would be a better approach in terms of time and memory?

I am using Spring MVC, Hibernate and Mysql.

Comment: Would suggest to process all forms as users can change anything on any form so you dont have to worry about which form changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Put your form values in persistent model objects.
- Merge them (in hibernate Session i.e. call saveOrUpdate())
- Flush the session and hibernate will take care of the sql.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I guess I should follow batch update then as suggested by everyone...

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to simply do a mass update.  Not only is this simpler to implement, but the query that you would have to use to get the data to compare to see if it's changed is going to cost as much as the query to insert the same data anyway.